# Codes I don't know when creating a makefile in c

Tags: c, makefile

```
NAME    := libft.a

CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I. -c

FILES   := $(shell find . -type f -name "ft_*.c")
OBJ     := $(FILES:%.c=%.o)

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    ar -rcs $(NAME) $(OBJ)

clean:
    @rm -f *.o

fclean: clean
    @rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

can u explain what does it do ? `= -I.` , Files section , `%` , `$` , `ar -rcs`

Comment: `-I.` has nothing to do with `make`, it's just a compiler option to specify the directory to search for header files. `ar -rcs` is the archive command for creating libraries, it also has nothing to do with `make`. The other stuff should be explained in a `make` tutorial.

Comment: Just FYI, it's a very bad idea to add the `-c` option to `CFLAGS`.

Comment: Also the `clean` rule `rm -f *.o` is wrong: that only cleans objects in the current directory but your makefile builds all the source files in all subdirectories.  You probably want `rm -f $(OBJ)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`CFLAGS  := -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I. -c` set the variable `CFLAGS` to the value `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -I. -c`.  This variable is used in an implicit rule to compile c programs so it's arguments to your c-compiler.

`OBJ     := $(FILES:%.c=%.o)` sets a variable just like above and it does that by changing the extension .c to .o of the files listed in the variable `FILES`.

`ar` is a program used to create an archive (.a file).  `-rcs` are arguments to said program:

> c   Create the archive.
> r   Insert the files member... into archive (with replacement).
> s   Write an object-file index into the archive, or update an existing